# Is there a way to get the name of a complex enum in c#?

Tags: c#, enums

I have a java program which I tried to copy in c# with enums.

```
public class TelevisionShop
{
    public static readonly TelevisionShop SAMSUNG = new TelevisionShop(100, 32, 65);
    public static readonly TelevisionShop LG = new TelevisionShop(80, 45, 75);
    public static readonly TelevisionShop SKYWORTH = new TelevisionShop(50, 32, 55);
    public static readonly TelevisionShop SONY = new TelevisionShop(70, 24, 55);
    public static readonly TelevisionShop SHARP = new TelevisionShop(20, 32, 55);

    public static IEnumerable<TelevisionShop> Values
    {
        get
        {
            yield return SAMSUNG;
            yield return LG;
            yield return SKYWORTH;
            yield return SONY;
            yield return SHARP;
        }
    }

    private readonly int Pcs;
    private readonly int Minsize;
    private readonly int Maxsize;

    TelevisionShop(int pc, int mi, int ma) => (Pcs, Minsize, Maxsize) = (pc, mi, ma);
```

I want a function which returns the data like this:

```
SAMSUNG: 100 pcs, 32 - 65
LG: 80 pcs, 45 - 75
SKYWORTH: 50 pcs, 32 - 55
SONY: 70 pcs, 24 - 55
SHARP: 20 pcs, 32 - 55
```

The question is, how could I get the names of the different enums like in java with `.name()`, so I could use a `foreach (var ts in TelevisionShop.Values)` to write this? I can write the other values

Comment: "which I tried to copy in c# with enums" - your code doesn't contain any enums at the moment... If you want to use a class like this, just add a `Name` property and a corresponding constructor parameter. (I'd also strongly advise you to follow .NET naming conventions, expose properties instead of fields, and make your constructor parameter names more readable.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be better if you added a separate Factory class to create TelevisionShop instances.

```
    //Factory class that creates television shop instances
    public class TelevisionShopFactory
    {
        //Could also add separate methods for each TV manufacturer
        public TelevisionShop GetSamsungTelevisionShop() =>
                new TelevisionShop("SAMSUNG", 100, 32, 65);

        public IEnumerable<TelevisionShop> GetTelevisionShops() =>
            new[]{
                new TelevisionShop("SAMSUNG", 100, 32, 65),
                new TelevisionShop("LG", 80, 45, 75),
                new TelevisionShop("SKYWORTH", 50, 32, 55),
                new TelevisionShop("SONY", 70, 24, 55),
                new TelevisionShop("SHARP", 20, 32, 55)
            };
    }

    public class TelevisionShop
    {
        public string Name { get; private set; }
        public int Pcs { get; private set; }
        public int Minsize { get; private set; }
        public int Maxsize { get; private set; }

        //Updated constructor to be a bit more readable
        public TelevisionShop(string name, int pcs, int minsize, int maxsize)
        {
            Name = name;
            Pcs = pcs;
            Minsize = minsize;
            Maxsize = maxsize;
        }
    }
```